# How do I universally reference self.view?

Tags: ios, swift, view

I have a reusable alertController component that is referenced to create an alertController throughout the app. I am trying to add a blur effect but I am unable to reference the view that the alertController is always on top of.

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

blurVisualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds

let vc = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

let alertActions = (actions.map { a in UIAlertAction(title: a.display, style: .default, handler: { _ in then() ; a.handler?() }) })

for action in alertActions {
    vc.addAction(action)
    blurVisualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}

if actions.isEmpty {
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Something went wrong", style: .default) { _ in then() }
    vc.addAction(action)
}

self.view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)
```

The error that I am getting is

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showBluredAlert(_ actions:[Model]) {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurVisualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds 
        self.view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)

        // add the alert here

    }
}
```

Then call it inside any vc instance with

```
showBluredAlert(<#[Model]#>)
```

---

Also don't forget this line

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a `Notification`. `Notification`s allow different parts of your app to communicate with one another. First, add an observer within whatever class your alert controller is created within:

```swift
class myClass: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlertController), name: "ShowAlertController", object: nil)
    }

    @objc func showAlertController() {
        //Within this function, add the code that will show the alert controller
    }
}
```

Now, from any other view controller within your application, you can post to the `Notification` named "ShowAlertController" and this `showAlertController()` method will be called:

```swift
class someViewController {

    //Pressing this button should make the alert controller appear
    @IBAction buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "ShowAlertController", object: nil)
    }
}
```

Its hard to say that this approach will work for you, as I am not sure the context in which the code you provided is being used, but assuming you have some sort of containing view controller, within which other view controllers are contained, then this approach should work for you.

Ideally, you would want to make an extension to `UIViewController` like Sh_Khan suggested, but if you have to, within one class, reference methods from another class, `Notification`s are one solution.

Comment: Thank you so much but I don't think this will work because there is only a free function where we are assembling the alertController, or maybe I'm wrong, any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every view controller has a reference to its [parent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent).  If you want the view of the parent viewController its `parent?.view`.  In addition every modal can get its [presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller). I would just add the blur to the alert controller's view though, as its generally bad for to go messing with the internals of another object that you don't own:

```
vc.view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)
```

Comment: Yes but I don't have any access to the view controller, but I completely understand hence why i need a way to access the top most view controller on the navigation stack outside of any view because this is a free function where the alertController is being assembled, I hope this clears up the confusion, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You can grab the top view controller's view like so `(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController.view` but thats making an awful lot of assumptions about the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I was adding the blurrEffect in the wrong place, which was my fault.